# How to have the sum of a related models column in Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, model, eloquent, sum, relationship

I have a hasMany relation on my user model

```php
public function timesheet()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TimeTable', 'employee');
    }
```

and I would like to have the sum of a column

```php
$users = User::select('firstname','lastname')->with('timesheet')->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    //sume of $user->timesheet
    //tried $user->timesheet->sum('minutes') which return on each iteration 0
}
```

What is the best approach to get the right result?

the problem lays on the issue that I use select fileds on User object. On the other hand the sum is really expensive and I get `Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted`

Comment: Is the content of `$user->timesheet` correct? What's the result of `$user->timesheet->pluck('minutes')`?

Comment: `$total = $user->timesheet->sum('minutes');` should just work. What do you see when you do a `dd($user->timesheet);` in the foreach loop. You should be able to see all related TimeTable entries there. If not, you might want to check your keys and/or query (debugbar package). Besides that, your code is bound to get slow as it currently fetches all users and for each user all timetable entries associated with it.

Comment: I made an update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the eager loading to work you have to select the `users.id` column:

```
$users = User::select('id', 'firstname', 'lastname')->with('timesheet')->get();
```

If you only fetch the `timesheet` models for the minutes, you can use a modified `withCount()`:

```php
User::withCount(['timesheet as minutes' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('sum(minutes)'));
}])->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->minutes
}
```

Comment: Is that really going to return the sum of minutes? I'd expect it to always return 1, to be honest.

Comment: @Namoshek It does.

Comment: Then there should really be an overload like `withSum()` for this. Think I need to give this a go tomorrow...

Comment: Thanks! it works but the collection sum is quite slow, is there a better approach?

Comment: nevermind `$query->select(DB::raw('sum(minutes)'));` works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
$users_with_time = $users->keyBy('id')->map(function($user) {
    return $user->sum('timesheets.minutes');
});
```

It is taking your collection of users, keys them by the user's `id` and them maps the resultant collection by the sum of the `minutes` property of the `timesheets` Eloquent Collection.

You should be left with a Support Collection of total time spent per user id.

I have not had time to test this but it should be a good place to start from.